# Get element from Gtk.ComboBox in vala

Tags: gtk, gtk3, glade, vala

I did this code in glade:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.16.0 on Wed Apr 30 19:25:13 2014 -->
<interface>
<!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.10 -->
  <object class="GtkListStore" id="dinero">
  <columns>
    <!-- column-name extraer -->
    <column type="gint"/>
  </columns>
<data>
  <row>
    <col id="0">20</col>
  </row>
  <row>
    <col id="0">50</col>
  </row>
  <row>
    <col id="0">100</col>
  </row>
  <row>
    <col id="0">200</col>
  </row>
  <row>
    <col id="0">300</col>
  </row>
  <row>
    <col id="0">500</col>
  </row>
</data>
</object>
<object class="GtkListStore" id="tipo_cuenta">
<columns>
  <!-- column-name cuenta -->
  <column type="gchararray"/>
</columns>
<data>
  <row>
    <col id="0" translatable="yes">Cuenta Corriente</col>
  </row>
  <row>
    <col id="0" translatable="yes">Cuenta de Ahorro</col>
  </row>
</data>
</object>
<object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
<property name="can_focus">False</property>
<child>
  <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="halign">center</property>
    <property name="valign">start</property>
    <property name="hexpand">True</property>
    <property name="vexpand">True</property>
    <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
    <property name="homogeneous">True</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box2">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkBox" id="box3">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="xpad">80</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Extraer</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkComboBox" id="comboextraer">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="halign">center</property>
                <property name="valign">center</property>
                <property name="model">dinero</property>
                <property name="wrap_width">3</property>
                <property name="row_span_column">3</property>
                <property name="column_span_column">3</property>
                <property name="active">0</property>
                <property name="button_sensitivity">on</property>
                <property name="id_column">0</property>
                <property name="active_id">extraer</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="lista_extraer"/>
                  <attributes>
                    <attribute name="visible">0</attribute>
                    <attribute name="text">0</attribute>
                    <attribute name="wrap-width">2</attribute>
                  </attributes>
                </child>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">True</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkBox" id="box4">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkLabel" id="label2">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="xpad">76</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Tipo de cuenta</property>
                <attributes>
                  <attribute name="font-desc" value="&lt;Introducir valor&gt; 10"/>
                  <attribute name="scale" value="1"/>
                </attributes>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkComboBox" id="comboextraer1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="halign">center</property>
                <property name="valign">center</property>
                <property name="model">tipo_cuenta</property>
                <property name="wrap_width">3</property>
                <property name="row_span_column">3</property>
                <property name="column_span_column">3</property>
                <property name="active">0</property>
                <property name="button_sensitivity">on</property>
                <property name="id_column">0</property>
                <property name="active_id">extraer</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="lista_extraer1"/>
                  <attributes>
                    <attribute name="visible">0</attribute>
                    <attribute name="text">0</attribute>
                    <attribute name="wrap-width">2</attribute>
                  </attributes>
                </child>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">True</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="expand">True</property>
        <property name="fill">False</property>
        <property name="position">0</property>
      </packing>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box5">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="boton">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Sacar dinero</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="margin_left">3</property>
            <property name="margin_right">6</property>
            <property name="margin_top">9</property>
            <property name="margin_bottom">6</property>
            <property name="relief">half</property>
            <property name="image_position">bottom</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="verificar">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="margin_left">33</property>
            <property name="margin_right">40</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Verificar</property>
            <attributes>
              <attribute name="scale" value="1"/>
            </attributes>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="Deposito">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="margin_left">74</property>
            <property name="margin_right">64</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Deposito</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="expand">False</property>
        <property name="fill">True</property>
        <property name="position">1</property>
      </packing>
    </child>
  </object>
</child>
</object>
```

And I did this code in Vala language:

```cs
using Gtk;

class Cajero : GLib.Object {

public Cajero(){
    int deposito = 3000;
    var builder = new Builder();
    builder.add_from_file("cajero.ui");
    builder.connect_signals(null);
    var ventana = builder.get_object("window1") as Window;
    ventana.title = "Cajero Automático";
    ventana.destroy.connect(Gtk.main_quit);
    var contenedor = builder.get_object("box1") as Box;
    var caja1 = builder.get_object("box2") as Box;
    var caja2 = builder.get_object("box3") as Box;
    var label1 = builder.get_object("label1") as Label;
    var combo_extraer = builder.get_object("comboextraer") as ComboBox;
    var lista_extraer = builder.get_object("lista_extraer") as CellRendererText;
    var caja3 = builder.get_object("box4") as Box;
    var label2 = builder.get_object("label2") as Label;
    var combo_cuenta = builder.get_object("comboextraer1") as ComboBox;
    var lista_cuenta = builder.get_object("lista_extraer1") as CellRendererText;
    var caja4 = builder.get_object("box5") as Box;
    var boton = builder.get_object("boton") as Button;
    var label3 = builder.get_object("verificar") as Label;
    var label4 = builder.get_object("Deposito") as Label;
    boton.clicked.connect(() => {
        int extraer = combo_extraer.get_active();
        int cuenta = combo_cuenta.get_active();
        if(cuenta == 1){
            if(extraer > 200){
                label3.set_label("Incorrecto");
            }else{
                label3.set_label("Correcto");
                deposito = deposito - extraer;
                if(deposito < 0){
                    ventana.title = "Fuera de servicio";
                    deposito = deposito + extraer;
                    label4.set_label(deposito.to_string());
                }else{
                    label4.set_label(deposito.to_string());
                }
            }
        }else{
            if(extraer > 400){
                label3.set_label("Incorrecto");
            }else{
                label3.set_label("Correcto");
                deposito = deposito - extraer;
                if(deposito < 0){
                    ventana.title = "Fuera de servicio";
                    deposito = deposito + extraer;
                    label4.set_label(deposito.to_string());
                }else{
                    label4.set_label(deposito.to_string());
                }
            }
        }
    });
    ventana.show_all(); 
}

public static int main(string[] args) {
    Gtk.init(ref args);
    Cajero cajero = new Cajero();
    Gtk.main();
    return 0;
}
}
```

I don't know how I can get the element value of combo_extraer. I get the active element position only with this Vala code but I can't get its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the value from the `ListStore` that is used by the `CombobBox`.

Basically you call `get_active_iter` on the `ComboBox` to get an iterator to the active entry and then you call `get_value` with that iterator and the column you want to retrieve from the list store.

Your list store is called `dinero`, you have to get it from the builder, as you already do for the other components.

The [example in valadoc](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.ComboBox) shows how it is done in general:

```cs
public class Application : Gtk.Window {
    public Application () {
        // Prepare Gtk.Window:
        this.title = "My Gtk.ComboBox";
        this.window_position = Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER;
        this.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);

        // Create & fill a ListStore:
        Gtk.ListStore list_store = new Gtk.ListStore (2, typeof (string), typeof (int));
        Gtk.TreeIter iter;

        list_store.append (out iter);
        list_store.set (iter, 0, "Burgenland", 1, 13);
        list_store.append (out iter);
        list_store.set (iter, 0, "Carinthia", 1, 17);

        // The Box:
        Gtk.ComboBox box = new Gtk.ComboBox.with_model (list_store);
        this.add (box);

        Gtk.CellRendererText renderer = new Gtk.CellRendererText ();
        box.pack_start (renderer, true);
        box.add_attribute (renderer, "text", 0);
        box.active = 0;

        renderer = new Gtk.CellRendererText ();
        box.pack_start (renderer, true);
        box.add_attribute (renderer, "text", 1);
        box.active = 0;

        box.changed.connect (() => {
            Value val1;
            Value val2;

            box.get_active_iter (out iter);
            list_store.get_value (iter, 0, out val1);
            list_store.get_value (iter, 1, out val2);

            stdout.printf ("Selection: %s, %d\n", (string) val1, (int) val2);
        });
    }

    public static int main (string[] args) {
        Gtk.init (ref args);

        Application app = new Application ();
        app.show_all ();
        Gtk.main ();
        return 0;
    }
}
```